# OpenApi 3 codegen java how to implement

Tags: java, spring-boot, gradle, openapi, openapi-generator

Have an openapi yml file with contains a simple get request with response, from this yml have the java files below been generated (among others).

How should these java files be used?
How to hook into the generated files?

Could simply copy the generated main and controller class into the main source tree, but does not seem to be the correct way.

--- edit ---

In the generated Controller class, how do I override the default responses that exist in the interface ExampleApi? Without having to modify the generated Controller class and have it in the VCS.

--- edit ---

build.gradle.kts

```
...
openApiGenerate {
    generatorName.set("spring")

    inputSpec.set("$rootDir/specs/api-example.yml")
    outputDir.set("$buildDir/generated")

    apiPackage.set("com.example.openapi.generated.api")
    invokerPackage.set("com.example.openapi.generated.invoker")
    modelPackage.set("com.example.openapi.generated.model")

    configOptions.set(mapOf(
            "dateLibrary" to "java8"
    ))
    systemProperties.set(mapOf(
            "modelDocs" to "false"
    ))
}
...
```

What should be done with these classes?

```
package com.example.openapi.generated.invoker;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.Module;
import org.openapitools.jackson.nullable.JsonNullableModule;
import org.springframework.boot.CommandLineRunner;
import org.springframework.boot.ExitCodeGenerator;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.CorsRegistry;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurer;

@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"com.example.openapi.generated.invoker", "com.example.openapi.generated.api" , "org.openapitools.configuration"})
public class OpenAPI2SpringBoot implements CommandLineRunner {

    @Override
    public void run(String... arg0) throws Exception {
        if (arg0.length > 0 && arg0[0].equals("exitcode")) {
            throw new ExitException();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        new SpringApplication(OpenAPI2SpringBoot.class).run(args);
    }

    static class ExitException extends RuntimeException implements ExitCodeGenerator {
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

        @Override
        public int getExitCode() {
            return 10;
        }

    }

    @Bean
    public WebMvcConfigurer webConfigurer() {
        return new WebMvcConfigurer() {
            /*@Override
            public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
                registry.addMapping("/**")
                        .allowedOrigins("*")
                        .allowedMethods("*")
                        .allowedHeaders("Content-Type");
            }*/
        };
    }

    @Bean
    public Module jsonNullableModule() {
        return new JsonNullableModule();
    }

}
```

```
package com.example.openapi.generated.api;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.context.request.NativeWebRequest;
import java.util.Optional;

@Controller
@RequestMapping("${openapi.basic.base-path:}")
public class ExampleApiController implements ExampleApi {

    private final NativeWebRequest request;

    @org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired
    public ExampleApiController(NativeWebRequest request) {
        this.request = request;
    }

    @Override
    public Optional<NativeWebRequest> getRequest() {
        return Optional.ofNullable(request);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to tell gradle to compile the files, there is no need to copy them.

Add the path with the generated files to the `sourceSets` of your project. Something like this:

```
sourceSets {
    main {
        java {
            srcDir("$buildDir/generated")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The generated classes are already part of the sourceSets, but how do I customize the response of a request? In the generated Controller class, how do I override the default responses that exist in the interface ExampleApi?

Comment: you can extend the generated controller or you tell the generator to create the interfaces only and implement the interfaces.

Comment: Resolved the issue by only generating the interface and implementing the controller on my own.

Comment: how would I tell openapi to use my implementation instead of the implementation it creates? Right now I'm just manually editing the generated files to add my implementation of the interface

Comment: there is an `interfaceOnly` config option in the [spring settings](https://openapi-generator.tech/docs/generators/spring).